# Find one excluded element from an Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Suppose we have K elements numbered from 0 to K-1. An array called A with the size of n, contains at most K-1 of our elements. Find one excluded element in A in time of O(n) and extra space of O(1).

For example, suppose we our elements are 0,1,2,3,4 and A is [4,2,3].
I think our extra space should be used for the sum of elements in array but I don't know how to find one of the missing elements from that sum.

Comment: explain your approaches first, what have you done? where you got stuck?

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are expected to show what you have tried and what exactly is unclear to you. It would also help if you give one or two simple examples. This is not a platform that will do homework for you. Thanks.

Comment: sort A, then it's trivial.

Comment: @stark Comparison-based sort can not be realized in `O(n)`, it is `Omega(n log n)`. Also, other sortings, like counting-sort, can not be applied due to the space-restriction of `O(1)`. OP is likely expected to re-use the provided array as space and abuse it to memorize without losing information. So maybe some sort of modified counting-sort could be applied.

Comment: I believe the problem is not correctly fomulated in the question but it sounds to me a classical algorithmic problem - if *exactly one* number is missing and all the others are present once (or odd number of times) you simply need to xor all the numbers and xor them with the xor of all numbers from 0 to k -1

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, I believe you can actually solve the problem as stated.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Zabuzard leads to the solution, counting sort uses an extra array to keep trace of the placement of the elements, but we don't need the extra array here as we know that all values are unique.

The idea is to place all elements at their index position in the array, adjusted for the smaller size of the array, where the middle part will be truncated.

Totally untested code

```
if (K-1 == A.size())
  return -1; // error
auto min = 0;
auto max = A.size()-1; // max element will be stored here
auto offset = K-max-1; // K=5, max = 2

while (min < max) {
  auto cand = A[min];
  if (cand != min) {
    std::swap(A[min], A[cand-offset]); // will only be called once per value -> O(1)

    // adjust maximum found
    while (A[max] == cand) {
      --max; // will only be called once per value -> O(1)
      --cand;
    }
  }
  
  // is the new value of min in its correct position
  if (A[min] == min)
    ++min;
}

return min;
```